# Webpack library - how to configure webpack to expose classes?

Tags: webpack

(JS purists, please excuse my use of the term 'class').

Am compiling a large tree of classes into a library. The bundle file name is given as the main entrypoint class of the application.

Looking in the file that Webpack outputs, only the entrypoint class is exposed as a function. All other classes that are bundled are defined as vars containing IIFEs.

So

```
function MainEntryPoint() {
    ...
}

MainEntryPoint.prototype.load = function(params) {
    ...
};
module.exports = MainEntryPoint;
```

When consuming the library, I can instantiate the main class:

```
let main = new MyLibrary.EntryPointClass();
```

All other classes in the library output file are IFFEs:

```
var MyOtherClass = function () {
    ... 
}();
exports.default = MyOtherClass
```

So trying to do:

```
let myInstance = new MyLibrary.MyOtherClass();
```

does not work. How do I expose other classes in the library?

Comment: what version of webpack do you use?

Comment: We were on 1.14 but I've updated it to 2.6 for this project.

Comment: Use [exports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#exports-loader). There is how to make your libary global